# Multiple if statements within loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have an R script that retrieves CSV files from a daily email in my outlook and then depending whether the date in email subject is greater than a set date, moves them to a specific folder.
The code is splitting the subject line to extract the date - the position of which can be in one of two places in the string, due to recent changes.

I have an if statement built which can successfully locate the date within the string in either circumstance, but I can't then use a second if statement to see if the output from the first if statement is greater than the sample date.

Below is the code I am trying to execute (I have included data that can be reproduced):

```
# Test data
testLoop <- c("[EXTERNAL] Test Promo Sessions was executed at 28062019 100005",
              "[EXTERNAL] Test Promo Sessions was executed at 29062019 100023",
              "Test Promo Sessions was executed at 30062019 100007",
              "Test Promo Sessions was executed at 01072019 100043",
              "Test Promo Sessions was executed at 02072019 100049",
              "Test Promo Sessions was executed at 03072019 100001")

# Example date
todaysDateFormatted2 <- '30062019'

# Loop
for(i in testLoop){
  if(if(nchar(i) == 51){
    strptime(sapply(strsplit(i, "\\s+"), "[", 7),"%d%m%Y")
  } else {
    strptime(sapply(strsplit(i, "\\s+"), "[", 8),"%d%m%Y")
  } > strptime(todaysDateFormatted2,"%d%m%Y")){
    print("greater than - move file")
  } else {
    print("not greater than - do nothing")
  }
}
```

When attempting the execute this code, I get the following error, however I'm not sure how to interpret it:

```
[1] "not greater than - do nothing"
[1] "not greater than - do nothing"
Error in if (if (nchar(i) == 51) { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (if (nchar(i) == 51) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Please, double check line `if(if(nchar(i) == 51){`. It looks a bit strange. At least, there is a missing closing parenthesis, probably.

Comment: As @Uwe metioned, change that line of code to `if (nchar(i) == 51{`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several flaws in your code. The duplicated `if` was weird, and you `strptime` into nowhere if you don't assign it to something, below `t`. Also you may want to assign the `else` condition to `t`. Now you can compare `t` to `todaysDateFormatted2` and print the result for each iteration.

```
for (i in testLoop) {
  if (nchar(i) == 51) {
    t <- strptime(sapply(strsplit(i, "\\s+"), "[", 7),"%d%m%Y")
  } else {
    t <- strptime(sapply(strsplit(i, "\\s+"), "[", 8),"%d%m%Y")
  }
  if (t > strptime(todaysDateFormatted2,"%d%m%Y")) {
    print("greater than - move file")
  } else {
    print("not greater than - do nothing")
  }
}

# [1] "not greater than - do nothing"
# [1] "not greater than - do nothing"
# [1] "not greater than - do nothing"
# [1] "greater than - move file"
# [1] "greater than - move file"
# [1] "greater than - move file"
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the OP fails because R does not consistently resolve the inner `if()` statement to a vector of length 1, which causes the outer `if()` to fail as described in the OP.

If the intent of the code is to decide whether to move a file based on the date in a file name, a simpler version of the code can accomplish what is desired. Here, we reduce the levels of nesting by using `lapply()` and saving the output from the original inner `if()` clause to an object. We then compare the saved object to the object representing today's date and write a message to the R log.

```
# Test data
testLoop <- c("[EXTERNAL] Test Promo Sessions was executed at 28062019 100005",
              "[EXTERNAL] Test Promo Sessions was executed at 29062019 100023",
              "Test Promo Sessions was executed at 30062019 100007",
              "Test Promo Sessions was executed at 01072019 100043",
              "Test Promo Sessions was executed at 02072019 100049",
              "Test Promo Sessions was executed at 03072019 100001")

# Example date
todaysDateFormatted2 <- '30062019'


datesProcessed <- lapply(testLoop,function(x){
     if(nchar(x) == 51) y <- strptime(sapply(strsplit(x, "\\s+"), "[", 7),"%d%m%Y")
     else y <- strptime(sapply(strsplit(x, "\\s+"), "[", 8),"%d%m%Y")
     if(y > strptime(todaysDateFormatted2,"%d%m%Y")) message("greater than - move file")
     else message("not greater than - do nothing")
     y
})
```

...and the output:

```
> datesProcessed <- lapply(testLoop,function(x){
+      if(nchar(x) == 51) y <- strptime(sapply(strsplit(x, "\\s+"), "[", 7),"%d%m%Y")
+      else y <- strptime(sapply(strsplit(x, "\\s+"), "[", 8),"%d%m%Y")
+      if(y > strptime(todaysDateFormatted2,"%d%m%Y")) message("greater than - move file")
+      else message("not greater than - do nothing")
+      y
+ })
not greater than - do nothing
not greater than - do nothing
not greater than - do nothing
greater than - move file
greater than - move file
greater than - move file
>
```